# SQL ERROR When trying to add related product Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Trying to add a related product in Magento to an existing product and I'm getting this error message below.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`freemypi_magento`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNK_TYPE_ID_CAT_PRD_LNK_TYPE_LNK_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`link_type_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_link_type` (`link_type_)

I have tried re-indexing, reparing sql, clearing cache, changing all sql things to innodb nothing seems to work :(

ANY HELP MUCH Appreciated

Comment: Could you show the code that fails?

Comment: Check if the value in link_type_id exists in catalog_product_link_type.link_type_

Answer (score 0):

it's not good way but you can try :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

before execute the query.

Comment: if you trying add by sql, paste in here pls.

Comment: also, the problem might be related with table prefixes.